# Connect PC with other LAN over the internet

Tags: networking, vpn, nat

I have a two PC and Two LAN network both under a NAT, I need to connect one of them to the other network over the internet.

PC(A) <----> {NAT/Router(X)} <--------- Internet ---------> {NAT/Router(Y)} <----> PC(B)

```
           192.168.0.0/24                            10.0.0.0/24
```

I need PC(A) to have an IP from 10.0.0.0 if passable, or at least PC(B) forward any traffic to PC(A).

dose VPN over cloud will work in this case? and how should i setup the server and the client? any guides will be helpful.

*I forget to mention that i have no control of the Port Forwarding!

Comment: You can't port forward on either side of this scenario?

Comment: I can port forward on the Router (X). but i prefer not to do it if passable.

Comment: Well, you can port-forwarded on one end and run a vpn server yourself. Or you can mess around with a paid service which may or may not put the devices in the same subnet so you can access your PC's across it. That depends on the vpn provider.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart let's say i can do that and this what i originally thought about it. The problem in this case that i need the server to access the Client network throw VPN is it possible? i can configure a OpenVPN without a VPN provider.

Comment: When you have it setup right, both sides can bidirectionally communicate with both networks. You would run the client-side on a router, that way you can access each device that connects to the client side network when ever they join. You wouldn't need client side software for each end station.

Comment: Openvpn would be my suggestion for the server. It's very well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at zerotier: https://www.zerotier.com/
It's an always on VPN, no logins.  You'll set up a network, authorize and add the two computers to it with your specific IP addresses, and then you've got essentially a LAN connection between the two.

https://www.zerotier.com/manual.shtml

Comment: I will Check it out. It look promising  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't port forward on either end, then an intermediary is going to be required. LogMeIn has a service called Hamachi that does something like this:

https://www.vpn.net/

The Hamachi client is available for Windows, Mac OS and Linux.

Comment: What's it do, and how do you make it do it?

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome but i'm think of creating something with out connecting to unknown servers.

if you have any info how they do it then i replicate it  with AWS for example.