# How to connect two routers? — WAN

Tags: router, wan, windows-networking

I am trying to set up a single network consisting of two routers and their attached nodes over the internet between two cities, SanDiego and Chicago. Where anything attached to each router is visible including USB hubs.

The modems at each location are pass though. But I would have to use DNS as I am unable to get static IPs from both ISPs.

I have a pair of ASUS RT-AC68U (which has every feature networking and DHCP etc.. needed) but am not adverse to purchasing newer routers.

At one point I was able to connect a remote PC to the "other" router via VPN from Chicago to San Diego but I am looking to just turn everything on on both ends without any rigamarole or logging on and just automatically be connected as if one single network turning on.
Is this not a WAN where one router (SanDiego) is the main Network and the second Router (Chicago) connecting to it?

Do I need a CSU/DSU if I don't have a leased Line?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1303127/connect-pc-with-other-lan-over-the-internet    Something like that?

Comment: What do USB hubs have to do with the network?

Comment: This is a virtual LAN (with 1 subnet) that merges the local LANs behind both routers. This is a tricky case. Normal VPN operations normally have 2 subnets: Remote and local. And the VPN-client and server combo act as a virtual router between those 2. I'm sure the AsusWRT (or MerlinWRT) firmware can NOT do this single subnet merging. They only do traditional VPN.

Comment: @mtak Network attached USB hubs are a thing. You install a special driver on the PC that connects to the hub over the LAN and presents it locally on the PC as a virtual USB hub. Often used in virtualization clusters when VM's need access to e.g. a USB license dongle for an application. If the VM fails over to another host you don't want to have to physically move the dongle to that other host. (AnywhereUSB is a well-known brand of these.)